# How to generate a sparse version of a dense point cloud

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, game-engine

I have a large file of 3D point cloud each line in the form of

x(1) y(1) z(1) g(1)

...

...

x(n) y(n) z(n) g(n)

now due to cpu power limitation I can not display all of the 3D points and would like to only select a sub set of it. say only one fifth of the points.

If I do the following

```
while (){
if x(i) % 5 == 0 keep the 3d point
}
```

the result gets zibera pattern, so it does not look nice. What algorithm do you suggest to select best candidates to form a subset of points to form a sub 3D point cloud which is most similar to the original dense point cloud?

Thank you

The language does not matter ( matlab, java c, etc) what matters is how we make a sparser version of the original one.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to random sub-sampling mentioned in the first answer, you could try this:

1. Compute the bounding box the point cloud (axis-aligned or oriented bounding box),
2. Choose a cell size (the bounding box now contains W x H x D cells of this size),
3. Hash all the points of the point cloud to their respective cell grid and keep only N point(s) maximum per cell (N >= 1), or simpler, just drop or keep every Nth point.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with random subsampling?

```
f = fractionOfDataToKeep(); // between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%)
while() {
  r = rng(1.0); // pseudorandom number between 0 and 1
  if (r < f) keepThe3DPoint()
}
```

Comment: This assumes the data is uniformly distributed in space, which may or may not be a reasonable assumption.